# Windows 10 DNS caching oddity, can someone explain how this can happen?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-10

I was at a friend's house who has Consolidated DSL service (soo slow). She started having problems where Chrome (on her Windows 10 desktop) started reporting that it could not find the IP address for any well-known hosts. I connected my Windows 10 laptop directly to her Zyxel vmg4825-b10a dsl modem/router and tried "`ping google.com`". It said it couldn't find the IP address. A few minutes later, I tried again, and it worked, getting 4 replies with times in the tens of milliseconds range. A few minutes after that, I tried again, and it was back to reporting it was unable to find the IP address for google.com. This makes no sense to me, as I thought that Windows would cache the working IP address result for a whole lot longer than the time I was away.

Eventually, the problem went away on its own, so I could only conclude that Consolidated fixed a problem with its DNS servers. So I can't reproduce the problem.

I hadn't thought to try "`ipconfig /displaydns`" at the time. But subsequent experiments with the same laptop on my own FIOS network suggest that a ping of google.com causes the IP address to show up in the output of "`ipconfig /displaydns | grep google.com`" for  quite a while. Can anyone explain this behavior? Is there a fixed time that DNS lookups get cached? Can the remote DNS server cause Windows to flush its cache? I see that the output of `ipconfig/displaydns` does not include the IP address that was found for google.com, so maybe it's not really a cache, though I don't understand why it would remember the name without the address...

*On a completely different note*: I wanted to record the exact error message produced by the ping command when it failed to find the address for a name, so that I could include it here. So I tried ping with a non-existent domain. But I can't make it happen on my network at home, instead I get this:

```
$ ping blurfo.blurfo

Pinging blurfo.blurfo [92.242.140.21] with 32 bytes of data:
```

Any nonexistent name I can come up with gets mapped to 92.242.140.21. What's up with that??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Internet provider is intercepting non-existent domains and using them for advertising.

`whois` on the 92.242.140.21 IP address yields netname: BAREFRUIT-ERRORHANDLING and quick google search for it results in: https://www.barefruit.com/. Go there and you'll get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for this part. I have Verizon FIOS, certainly willing to take an extra buck wherever they can. So I gave you a point, but can't accept it as the answer, since it only answers a footnote to the question :-)

Comment: Well, DNS generally speaking is cached. And the record itself holds the information for how long it can and should be cached. But I am not using Windows and I've heard that it could behave oddly when it comes to name resolution so I'll refrain myself from answering. And BTW I've seen google resolvers (8.8.8.8) to purposefully lower the time to live setting.

Comment: Yeah, Windows behaviors can be puzzling at best. Like what's the point of having the displaydns option to ipconfig display names without addresses? But I guess you're suggesting that the Consolidated DNS server, when it successfully resolved google.com, could have given it a TTL that caused ipconfig to flush it sooner than what I'm seeing at home with Verizon.

Comment: Possible but this would likely require more thorough investigation.

Comment: Lord, how embarrassing. Here I am accusing the Windows ipconfig/displaydns command of not displaying the IP address to which each name resolves, when the problem was that I was grepping for a name, and the address is displayed on a separate line. Duh.